# How can I save an email's attachment to a shared folder when it arrives?

Tags: exchange, exchange-2007

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Automated extraction of email attachment on Exchange Server](https://serverfault.com/questions/86948/automated-extraction-of-email-attachment-on-exchange-server)

How can automatically save an email's attachment to a shared folder? I'm not an administrator, but I'm wondering if this is possible. I have a requirement to do this by code. I figured that if it can be done in Exchange itself is way better.

Answer (score 1):

Possible duplicate: [Automated extraction of email attachment on Exchange Server](https://serverfault.com/questions/86948/automated-extraction-of-email-attachment-on-exchange-server)

Did you see these already?  I don't want to relay you to google search, but a quick one found quite a few links to choose from besides the below.

http://www.pixelchef.net/content/rule-autosave-attachment-outlook

http://www.cypressnet.com/Products/autosave/attachment_saver.htm

http://community.spiceworks.com/scripts/show/361-auto-save-attachments-to-folder

Comment: I believe those solutions are for Outlook (Exchange client) and not the Exchange server itself. I would like to do it directly on the server if possible

Comment: -1 for a link-only answer. You've been around long enough to know that these are not good.

Comment: @EEAA - True...I'll change my answer and recommend this duplicate: http://serverfault.com/questions/86948/automated-extraction-of-email-attachment-on-exchange-server

Comment: @TheCleaner - thanks. In that case, though, just VTC as a dupe.